# Convert Json string to Json object array in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

Data is stored in String form as follows :

```
String jsonData = "{"name":"A","age":23},{"name":"B","age":24}";
```

I want to convert the above string into Array of Objects:

`Person[] persons;`

Where,

`persons[0].name` => "A"

`persons[0].age` => 23 ...and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Surround your string with `[` and `]` to create json representing array
2. Parse it with `Person[] persons = gson.fromJson(jsonStringWithBracets, Person[].class);`